# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"} - rake test fails but app works correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run my rake test it comes up with two errors. However, when I run my blog, the index, show, new, and edit views all work correctly and do not generate errors in the browser. How do my tests fail but my blog doesn't? I've looked through other answers on this topic but most seem to do with links or nested elements in methods. I have neither.

```
1) Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'


2) Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'
```

Here is my show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<h3> Posted: <%= @post.created_at.strftime("%I:%M %p") %> by Tarrence</h3>
<p><%= @post.body %></p>

</div>
<%= render 'sidebar' %>
```

Here is my edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

Here is my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.label :topic %>
  <%= f.text_field :topic, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<div class="blog-post">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h3><%= post.title %></h3>
            <span>Posted by Tarrence <%= post.created_at.strftime("at %I:%M %p") %></span><br>
            <span>Topic: <%= post.topic %></span>

            <% if post.body.length > 100 %>
                <p><%= truncate(post.body, length: 100, separator: ' ') %>
                <%= link_to "Read More", post_path(post) %></p>
            <% else %>
                <p><%= post.body %></p>
            <% end %>

            <hr>
        <% end %>

    </div>

    <nav class="pager">
        <%= will_paginate @posts %>
    </nav>


</div>
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
root 'posts#index'
#get 'post' => 'posts#show'
#get 'post/edit' => 'posts#edit'
resources :posts
```

Here is my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   # @posts = Post.all
   @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    logger.info "---params ==> #{params.inspect}---"
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private 

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :topic, :body)
    end
end
```

Here is my test

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @post = Post.create(title: "This is a post", topic: "Random", body: "This is some text in the body.")
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show, id: @post.id
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @post.id
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @post.valid?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the only thing you didn't show is the one place where the error is - your test!

...it doesn't matter though because it's clear what the problem is, you're not providing the `:id` in your test calls, ie. you'll be doing something like this in `test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb`

```
get :show
get :edit
```

...whereas what you should be doing is something like this:

```
post = Post.create attributes: "required", for: "a post"  # or maybe you use FactoryGirl, you get the idea though - create a post
get :show, id: post.id
```

Comment: Yea sorry about that. I was so worried about the other code that I forgot the most important part. Anyway your solution solved my problem. Thanks.